# How to avoid React component automatically binding 'this'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function like this:

```
obj = {
  func: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

It is passed to React component as a prop:

```
React.createElement(Component, {
  funcAsProp: obj.func
}
```

Then called in a react component like this:

```
let Component = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Component',

  clickHandler: function () {
    this.props.funcAsProp();
  },

  render: function () {
    return React.createElement('div', {
      onClick: this.clickHandler
    });
  }
});
```

When calling like this the obj.func this is the Component. I still have some confusion over Javascript 'this' and React automatic binding. Is the context binded  to obj.func by React or is this some fundamental Javascript thing I don't get here?

And if it is about automatic binding, how do I call the function without binding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `this` before you pass `obj.func` to props., because  `func` lost own context and uses React's component context

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'obj, name',
  
  func: function () {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};

let Component = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Component',

  clickHandler: function () {
    this.props.funcAsProp();
  },

  render: function () {
    return React.createElement('div', {
      onClick: this.clickHandler
    }, 'Click');
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Component, { funcAsProp: obj.func.bind(obj) }),
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `funcAsProp: obj.func` you lost your context. Now you have `funcAsProp` equals `func` and there is no information about `obj` anymore. Try this:

```
React.createElement(Component, {
  funcAsProp: obj
}
```

and in handler:

```
this.props.funcAsProp.func();
```

or you can bind your context:

```
React.createElement(Component, {
  funcAsProp: obj.func.bind(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` will be the context of the function call, so in this case it will be the `Component`. This is Javascript default behaviour, if you want your `function` to be bound to the original context you need to do something like this when declaring:

```
obj = {
  func: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }.bind(this);
}
```

or when passing the function down to the component:

```
React.createElement(Component, {   funcAsProp: obj.func.bind(this) }
```

Comment: Thats wrong, if you do this context will be not `obj`, it will be `window` for example if you in global scope in browser

Comment: The first suggestion sets this 'undefined'. I can bind it to window or some other object, but not itself.